# ASP.NET MVC URL Routing, With Hierarchy Structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do some routing in ASP.NET MVC, I wanted URLs to basically look like this for a certain area (AdminArea Section)

http://localhost/admin/folders/folder1/folder2

I want the structure above, however I am running into a few issues, which I cannot resolve.

The first issue is that sometimes the URL ends up as a querystring like

?permalink=foldername

which is not what I want.

Here is the route I have defined.

```
            context.MapRoute
        (
                "folder_route",
                "Administration/folders/{*permalink}",
                defaults: new { controller = "folders", action = "Index",permalink = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { permalink = new FolderURLConstraint() }

        );
```

The constraint:

```
    public class FolderURLConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (values[parameterName] != null)
        {
            var permalink = values[parameterName].ToString();
            return new FolderDAL().ValidateFolderURLSlug(permalink);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The validation:

```
        public bool ValidateFolderURLSlug(string folderName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName))
        {

            string[] splitFolder = folderName.Split(new string[] { "/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string lastValue = splitFolder[splitFolder.Length - 1];

            string[] folderNames = GetFolderBreadCrumb(lastValue.ToLower()).Select(p => p.FolderName.ToLower()).ToArray();;

            splitFolder = splitFolder.Select(s => s.ToLower()).ToArray();

            bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(splitFolder, folderNames);

            return isEqual;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

The index page:
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped",

```
    columns:grid.Columns(

            grid.Column("FolderName", "Folder Name",
            format:(item) => Html.ActionLink((string)item.FolderName, "index", "folders", new {permalink=item.FolderName}, null)),
            grid.Column("DateCreated", "Date Created"),
            grid.Column(header:"Action", format:
            @<text>
            <a href="@Url.Action("delete", "Folders", new {id=item.PrimaryKey })"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("edit", "Folders", new {id=item.PrimaryKey })"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a>
            </text>)

        )
```

)

I would like the HTML.ActionLink to generate urls like /folder1/folder2 so for example if you click on pages folder you'd get a url like /pages but when you click home folder in pages you'd get a url like /pages/home etc

I can't get that to work, also for some reason it seems to add the querystring after the first hierarchy drop.

so on the main page (/folders/) when you click a folder you'd go to

/pages/

but the folder inside pages (lets say home)

will have a link like /folders?permalink=Home

However if I type /pages/home, this still works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Agent47 i whould consider using another aproach.

Normally i create a custom handler and a custom html helper to override Html.ActionLink.

RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "IUrlRouteHandler",
       "{*url}",
       new[] { "YourApp.Controllers" }).RouteHandler = new UrlRouteHandler();
```

So, you need to implement a class named **UrlRouteHandler** that will receive any "url" for example http://localhost/admin/folders/folder1/folder2

```
public sealed class UrlRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
     public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var url = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
        var routeData = requestContext.RouteData.Values;

        // manage your rules here!

        routeData["controller"] = "YourController";
        routeData["action"] = "YourAction";

        return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Use url variable above to manage your rules and don't forget to provide the controller and action names. You can look url in database, in static classes, split all segments to decide which controller and action your application will response.